# Converting videos to flv using FFMPEG and losing the duration

Tags: flash, video, ffmpeg, flv, jwplayer

I use **FFMPEG** to convert some videos for the extension FLV, thereafter through an application is sent this video to a web page, where it is displayed through the **JW Player**. My problem happens on the website because the player does not display the total time of the video, thus I can not move forward or back my video. For conversion use the following code:

```
-i "{ArquivoOrigem}" -vcodec flv -f flv -r 29.97 -s 320x240 -aspect 16:9 -b 200k -ac 1 -ar 22050 -ab 56k d "{ArquivoDestino}"
```

So, is there any way I can do that?
tks

Comment: What version of JW Player are you using? Can you show the complete console output of your ffmpeg command? Is there a particular reason you're using the "flv" encoder instead of libx264?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display flash flv information and stream it on the web properly via jw player or any other player, flash flv video need meta information.

FFMPEG can't add meta information to flv videos by default after encoding. You need to use additional open source utility e.g http://rubyforge.org/projects/flvtool2/ to add meta information after encoding completed.

Comment: I used the following command:
flvtool2 U-file.flv file2.flv

And it worked correctly.

tks!!!

Comment: yea the following command will add all useful meta information to flv video which is required by player to stream it correctly. please mark my answer if it is useful for you.